# Generate delaunay triangulation from 3D(x,y,z) points

Tags: c++, visual-studio, triangulation-survey

I have 3D Points array.each 3D point have x,y,z data. I want to generate delaunay triangulation.I am new in delaunay triangulation. My array as below.
-256.24 85.35 5.0
-262.24 84.35 15.0
-263.24 87.35 25.0
................
I am working in c++ with Visual studio IDE.
I want to generate indexes of triangulation. As well as array of triangles points.

Comment: What software do you have?

Comment: I am using visual studio IDE and working in C++.

Answer (score 4):

Using scipy and numpy:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial import Delaunay

#do triangulation
points = np.random.rand(4, 3)
tri = Delaunay(points)

#indices
tri.simplices

#points
tri.points
```

See the documentation [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.Delaunay.html).